# How to fix "E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)"

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Unetbootin on Ubuntu but get the above error and this one:

```
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Can anybody tell me how to fix this so I can install Unetbootin successfully?

Comment: Could you give us at least some basic info about what you are doing? For instance, did you type a command? If so, what command was it? Did you click on something? What version of ubuntu are you currently running?

Answer (score 2):

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
>
> E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/)

These lines says that you are not authorized to install a package. You need root privileges to do it.

So, you must to use `sudo` to give permission to install the package:

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```